# SQL Server | storing output of select query to temp table using sp_MSforeachdb

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I want to execute select query on all databases starting with 'ABC_%' if the filename consist of '?'.

Wrote the below query for this purpose but it results nothing:

```
DECLARE @result TABLE (o varchar(250), h uniqueidentifier, i uniqueidentifier, k nvarchar(250))
INSERT INTO @result
EXEC sp_MSforeachdb 'Begin
USE [?]
IF DB_NAME() like ''ABC_%''
BEGIN
SELECT DB_NAME() as DatabaseName
      ,[FileId]
      ,[HRDataId]
      ,[FileName]
  FROM [?].[dbo].[UploadedFile]
where FileName like ''%?%''
END
End'
SELECT o
    ,h
    ,i
    ,k
    from @result;
```

But I am aware that some databases have some '?' in fileName field. but the result is always blank.

Regards,
Anjani

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was because of the ? is treated as database name in sp_MSforeachdb stored procedure. I escape using ? using:
`where FileName like ''%'' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(32), 0x3F) + ''%''`